# Shell : Check if all output strings are same

Tags: string, bash, shell, comparison

I have the following code snippet

```
$ mount | grep '^/dev'| awk '{print $1}'
 /dev/disk1s1
 /dev/disk1s4
```

Now I need to check if the output lines have the same value or different.
So in the above case it is different. [ disk1s1 and disk1s4 ]. How can this be achieved in shell.

I may have two or more lines in the result.

Comment: You can do with `awk`, pretty much everything you can do with `grep`. So `awk` along with `grep` is an overkill.. Also what should be your result. Is it just a single line with `same` or `different`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but something like:

```
if (( $(mount | grep -o '^/dev[^ ]*' | sort -u | wc -l) > 1 ))
then
  echo different values
fi
```

The -o option in grep together with the slightly modified pattern returns only the first field. The -u option of sort throws away duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Try to modify your command as followed, if you got any duplicated results, the output would append with "same"

```
$ mount | awk '/^\/dev/{print $1,a[$1]?"same":"";a[$1]=1}'
/dev/sdb1 
/dev/sdb3 
/dev/sda1 
/dev/sdb1 same
/dev/sdb3 same
```

Brief explanation,

- No need to use `grep` in your command, cause `awk` can do anything that `grep`can.
- `/^\/dev/`: search the lines start with '/dev'
- `a[$1]?"same":""` if a[$1] is set, print "same" behind `$1`, otherwise do nothing
- `a[$1]=1`: don't forget to set `$1` in the last.

Comment: @Allan Since `awk` support the (post/pre)fix  operator, you could further shorten that to `mount | awk '/^\/dev/{print $1,a[$1]++?"same":""}'`.

Comment: @Allan Being idiomatic with `awk` is always encouraged. The key is to practise. ;)